# The <<= operator in SBT Explained

Tags: scala, sbt

I am looking for a complete understanding of how the `<<=` operator works in SBT.

From SBT's [API](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/api/#sbt.SettingKey) it appears to accept a type `Initialize[T]` and resolves to a `Setting[T]`.  I presume this allows the user to initialize the `Settingkey`'s value given the value of other `SettingKey`. the documentation says nothing more ... on the topic.

The below code correctly resolves the publication Repository depending on  the value of `version`, but how does it work?

```
publishTo <<= version { (v: String) =>
    if (v.trim.endsWith("SNAPSHOT"))
        Some("Artifactory Realm" at "http://artifactory.erfangc.io/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local;build.timestamp=" + new java.util.Date().getTime)
    else
        Some("Artifactory Realm" at "http://artifactory.erfangc.io/artifactory/libs-release-local")
}
```

Specifically, how is it different from:

```
publishTo := {
    if (version.value.trim.endsWith("SNAPSHOT"))
        Some("Artifactory Realm" at "http://artifactory.erfangc.io/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local;build.timestamp=" + new java.util.Date().getTime)
    else
        Some("Artifactory Realm" at "http://artifactory.erfangc.io/artifactory/libs-release-local")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two forms are equivalent. As you correctly state, the purpose is to use the result of one setting in the definition of another setting. Internally this means that sbt establishes a dependency from `version` to `publishTo`.

The second form, where you "evaluate" a setting using `.value` inside the `:= { }` block of another setting, triggers a macro that rewrites the tree similarly to the first form. This syntax was introduced because the `<<=` operator (and related `<+=`) is difficult to understand and remember, especially by newcomers to sbt.

---

Note that in your example, you could also write `if (isSnapshot.value) Some(...) else Some(...)`. This is an auxiliary setting that checks for `"SNAPSHOT"` in `version`.

Comment: Thanks, I also just realized that SettingKey have an apply method that returns Initialize[Z], which makes the former form syntactically reasonable. Now this just raise the question how does the macro expansion from the latter get triggered ... Or is the dependency structure of SettingKeys entirely handled through lazy evaluation